# UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning when re-throw error from inner catch to outer catch

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise

I use Node Js 12. I have below code and error. I want to re-throw err from inner catch and catch it in outer one. How to modify my code to achieve error re-throw?? Thanks.

```
function test() {

  try {

    // Some other code before promise chain below that could cause exception

    return Promise.resolve()
      .then(() => {
        const e = new Error();
        e.message = 'testtest';
        e.statusCode = 404;
        throw e;
      })
      .catch(err => {
        console.log('==inner===', err);
        throw err;
      });
  
  
  
  } catch (err) {
    console.log('==outer===', err);
  }
}


test();
```

Error

```
jfan@ubuntu2004:~/Desktop/temp/d$ node index.js 
==inner=== Error: testtest
    at /home/jfan/Desktop/temp/d/index.js:17:19 {
  statusCode: 404
}
(node:34826) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: testtest
    at /home/jfan/Desktop/temp/d/index.js:17:19
(node:34826) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). To terminate the node process on unhandled promise rejection, use the CLI flag `--unhandled-rejections=strict` (see https://nodejs.org/api/cli.html#cli_unhandled_rejections_mode). (rejection id: 1)
(node:34826) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.
jfan@ubuntu2004:~/Desktop/temp/d$
```

Comment: What is the purpose of throwing the error from innner .catch and catch again in "outer" catch? Get rid of the inner .catch and your outer catch will have the error.

Comment: I have program that its promise chain in the try block cannot be modified (business restriction). But I need handle its error. So I'm thinking to use error re-throw.

Comment: @RaviKukreja no it won't. There's a difference between `.catch()` for rejected promises and a `try..catch`

Comment: @Phil Valid. Thanks for pointing out.

Answer (score 0):

## SUGGESTION

```
// define an async function for the purpose of awating a promise inside the function
// optional useError parameter is used to trigger an error for testing purposes
// optional args parameter is for passing any additional parameters to this function for example

async function test(useError=false, args=[]) {
  try {

    // Some other code before promise chain below that could cause exception
    if(useError) {
        throw new Error(`Some error occured while processing ${args[0]}...`);
    }

    // await the promise and store the result in a variable
    const promisedData = await Promise.resolve(`Promise delivered with ${args[0] ? args[0] : 'nothing'}!`);

    // return the result (this will be a promise)
    return promisedData;
  } catch (err) {
    // catch error that occurs within try block
    console.log('==outer===', err);
  }
}

// a simple generic async function runner for example
async function genericAsyncFunctionRunner(asyncFunction, ...args) {
    let [useError, ...otherArgs] = args;
    useError = useError ? true : false;
    const result = await asyncFunction(useError, otherArgs);

    // Output the result in console for example
    console.log(result);
}

// run asyn function using the generic async function runner with/without arguments 
genericAsyncFunctionRunner(test); // Promise delivered with nothing!
genericAsyncFunctionRunner(test, false, 'gratitude'); // Promise delivered with gratitude!
genericAsyncFunctionRunner(test, true, 'gratitude'); // ==outer=== Error: Some error occured while processing gratitude...
```